# How do I change Style Width of Div Element on Page load using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have the following div element;

```
 <div id="ProgressBar">
     <div id="ProgressBarPercentage" style="width: 50%" runat="server"></div>
 </div>
```

I would like it so that width goes from 0% to 50% incrementally and smoothly.

What I have tried so far (it does not work):

```
$(function () {
    $("#ProgressBarPercentage").each(function () {
        console.log("1");
        $(this)
            .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: $(this).data("origWidth")
            }, 1200);
     });
});
```

Im also trying to play around with :

```
function update() {
    var element = document.getElementById("ProgressBarPercentage");
    var width = 1;
    var identity = setInterval(scene, 10);
    function scene() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(identity);
        } else {
            width++;
            element.style.width = width + '%';
        }
    }
}
```

The above works on windows.load function but its not doing what I want it to do. I am a newbie to JS, any help?

UPDATE:

I would also like to make it smooth and incrementally done if I were to change the width in a  js function, like this:

```
document.getElementById("ProgressBarPercentage").style.width = 67%;
```

Comment: It is working,Try to check with a border or background

Comment: There is a JS library named Velocity that may provide smoother movement if the pure css option does not suffice.

Comment: I would like it so that width goes from 0% to 50% incrementally and smoothly. I am not sure what you mean @Shijin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Approach 1 (CSS Animation):

You can achieve this effect using a CSS animation alone.

This animation animates the width of `#ProgressBarPercentage` from `0` to `100%`.

**Working Example:**

```css
#ProgressBar {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#ProgressBarPercentage {
 height: 30px;
 background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
 animation: loadProgressBar 4s linear;
}

@keyframes loadProgressBar {

   0% {width: 0;}
 100% {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="ProgressBar">
<div id="ProgressBarPercentage"></div>
</div>
```

---

## Approach 2 (CSS Transition):

It's a little trickier to update CSS `@keyframes` values via javascript, so here is an alternative to the version above, this time using CSS `transition` rather than CSS `animation`.

The function will accept a parameter between 0 and 100. When the function runs, the `#ProgressBarPercentage` will transition from its current value to the new value.

**Working Example:**

```js
const progressBarPercentage = document.getElementById('ProgressBarPercentage');

const transitionProgressBar = (progress) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    progressBarPercentage.style.width = progress + '%';
  }, 200);
}

// INITIAL TRANSITION (on PAGE LOAD)
transitionProgressBar(32);

// SUBSEQUENT TRANSITIONS
setTimeout(() => {transitionProgressBar(59)}, 4000);
setTimeout(() => {transitionProgressBar(78)}, 8000);
setTimeout(() => {transitionProgressBar(96)}, 12000);
```

```css
#ProgressBar {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#ProgressBarPercentage {
 width: 0;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
 transition: width 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="ProgressBar">
<div id="ProgressBarPercentage"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but what if I made a function `document.getElementById("ProgressBarPercentage").style.width = 67%;`   I would want to change depending on he above smoothly and incrementally

Comment: You can alter the final width of `#ProgressBarPercentage` at the end of the animation by changing the line `100% {width: 100%;}` to `100% {width: 67%;}` - or whatever value you need.

Comment: I would want to change it via js please :)

Comment: See **Approach 2** above, which uses CSS `transition` instead of `animation` - this makes it easy to change the value of `#ProgressBarPercentage` via javascript.

Comment: Approach 2 works brilliantly with my code. Is there away I can have it that it remembers its previous width and it increases or decreases based on that?

Comment: How about using a HTML5 data-* attribute (accessible and updatable via .dataset in javascript) ? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I am now just getting one more error that I cant seem to fix:  Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: That suggests that you have a statement `[myElement].style.[myStyle]` but `[myElement]` doesn't (yet) exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something like this

```
div {
  width: 0%;
 -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  from {width: 0%;}
  to {width: 50%;}
}


<script>

  window. addEventListener('load', () => {

    const myDiv = document.getElementById("ProgressBarPercentage")
    myDiv.classList.add("example")

  })

</script>
```

Comment: Another Great function, but what if I made a function `document.getElementById("ProgressBarPercentage").style.width = 67%;`   I would want to change depending on he above smoothly and incrementally

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do something exactly on fage load you use

```
div {
  width: 0%;
 -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  from {width: 0%;}
  to {width: 50%;}
}


<script>
 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") { 
  // incase you want it on "ready state of page you can use interactive"
  const myDiv = document.getElementById("ProgressBarPercentage")
    myDiv.classList.add("example")
 }
}


</script>
```